# File Referencing in PHP

Tags: php, reference, include, document-root, file-structure

If i have a file at mysite.com/pages/page1.php and a file header.php, which is in the home directory (mysite.com/header.php), what's the way to include header.php?

I tried `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/header.php");` or `"../header.php");`

That doesn't work because nothing that is included or referenced inside header.php works. For example `include("meta.php");` doesn't work. Neither does `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/meta.php");`

Is there another way to call header.php that doesn't "move" it to the directory of the file calling it?

Comment: from `mysite.com/pages/page1.php` home would be `../../header.php`

Comment: Enable error reporting, an include doesn't silently fail.   Use realpath() and file_exists() to debug.

Comment: it just says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". I can get to header.php, but nothing that it references because it thinks header.php is now in the pages folder. At least I think that's why.

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` will give you the absolute path. Check where its pointing in your server. `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and also you can  append the filename after `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and check if its pointing to the real location and file.

Comment: hmm I have a css referenced in header.php, and looks like it's trying to find it at "https: //mysite.com/home/myname/mysite.com/css/styles.css". that doesn't seem right. But either way, I shouldn't have to modify anything in header.php because I know everything it calls works when it's called from the home directory. And header.php is in the home directory.

Answer (score 1):

PHP provides at least two "working paths" for your files :

- The function `getcwd()`, which returns the current working directory (it explains its name),
- The `dirname(__FILE__)`, which returns the current script's path.

You can find more informations here about `getcwd` :

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

According to the documentation of the `include` statement ( https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php ) :

> The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.
>
> [...]
>
> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing.

According to the doc, `include` will use the script's directory, which is in your case your current working directory (cwd).

---

## The situation

Now, you have the following situation :

- A file at `/meta.php`,
- A file at `/header.php`, which needs to include `/meta.php`,
- A file at `/pages/page1.php` which needs to include `/header.php`.

The question is : where is your working directory ?
If you run the script `/pages/page1.php`, your working directory is `/pages/`.

So, to access `/header.php`, you must use this statement inside `/pages/page1.php` :

```
include '../../header.php';
```

Or :

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header.php';
```

These statements are equivalents due to the path of `/header.php`.

In `/header.php`, the following statement will fail :

```
include 'meta.php';
```

Why ? Because your current working directory is `/pages/`, so `include 'meta.php';` refers to `include '/pages/meta.php';` which do not exist, resulting in an error. Remember that the `include` statement tries to use the current working directory if the URL is relative.

---

## A possible solution

To access to the `/meta.php` file from the `/header.php`, you can either :

- Use `include '../../meta.php';` in `/header.php` if you are calling your script from the `/pages/page1.php` file,
- Use `include dirname(__FILE__) . '/meta.php';` in `/header.php`,
- Use `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/meta.php';` in `header.php`.

In your case, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is probably the same that `dirname(__FILE__)`, because `/header.php` is at document root path. However, the former statement is only valid if `header.php` path is document root. The later is better because it only depends from the path of the current file.

---

## Which one to use ?

The second solution is probably better, because for instance the following statement in `/pages/subfolder/page.php` will fail :

```
include '../../../header.php';
```

The `/header.php` file will be properly included, but if it contains the `include '../../meta.php';` statement, it will refers to `include '/pages/meta.php';`, because your working subdirectory is `/pages/subfolder/`.

It is a good design to use the `dirname(__FILE__)` alternative when you want to include a script relatively from the current file, indepently from the current working directory. Just do not forget the final `/` because `dirname` gives the folder of the current script without it.

---

## In conclusion

In `/pages/page1.php`, use :

```
include '../../header.php';
```

In `/header.php`, use :

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/meta.php';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response :) I think i'm getting into meta.php now, but there are a bunch of links like "<script src="js/utility.js"></script>" in it that would also need something like  "dirname(__FILE__)". But those are not in php anymore.

Comment: i looked into getcwd() and found that apparently you can change the current working directory with chdir(). Seems like that's exactly what I need, if i can just put it at the top of pages that are not in mysite.com home directory. But it didn't seem to work.

Comment: it would be bad to have to edit the links in every file that may be included in page1.php since some of them might have hundreds of links in them.

Comment: I think there's an html tag which can help you :
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp